# runtime error: load of null pointer of type 'int'

Tags: c, pointers

The problem statement says **"Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target."**
I am getting a

> runtime error: load of null pointer of type 'int' with the below given code.

I tried various variations of the loop but did not seem to find out any working solution.

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){

    if (nums==NULL || numsSize==0 || returnSize==NULL){
        printf("Invalid args passes.");
        return NULL;    
    }

    if (*returnSize <= 0 || *returnSize > 16){
        printf("Invalid amount of memory being asked for!");
        return NULL;
    }

    int i=0,j=0;
    int *returnIndex = NULL;

    for (i=0 ; i<numsSize ; i++){
        for (j=(i+1) ; j<numsSize ; j++){
            if ((nums[i]+nums[j]) == (target)) {

                returnIndex = (int *)malloc((*returnSize) * (sizeof(int)));
                if (returnIndex==NULL){
                    printf("\nCould not allocate memory.\n");
                    return NULL;
                }

                returnIndex[0]=i;
                returnIndex[1]=j;               
                return returnIndex;
            }
        }
    }

    /* No match found with regards to target */
    return NULL;
}
```

I expect the program to print out the indexes of the addition of two numbers which meet the target.

Comment: You're confusing indices with pointers. An index is some arithmetic type that indicates the offset of an object in an array of that type of object. A pointer points directly to the memory address of the object. Even the function type is incorrect if you're supposed to return a index.

Comment: @Khilav Show how the function is called.

Comment: You're only returning two ints, use a small struct and ditch all that heap alloc stuff.

Comment: Please learn how to debug, in the most simple case by putting some `printf()` in your code to get the exact place of the failure. I'm sure you will find the problem then, and if not, please tell us your findings.